# Is the std::views namespace not available in Xcode's C++?

Tags: c++, xcode, c++20, std-ranges

I have Xcode 14 beta, and I tried to compile this [join example](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/ranges/join_view) from cppreference.com.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <ranges>
#include <string_view>
#include <vector>
 
int main()
{
    using namespace std::literals;
    const auto bits = { "https:"sv, "//"sv, "cppreference"sv, "."sv, "com"sv };
    for (char const c : bits | std::views::join) std::cout << c; // Error 1
    std::cout << '\n';
 
    const std::vector<std::vector<int>> v{ {1,2}, {3,4,5}, {6}, {7,8,9} };
    auto jv = std::ranges::join_view(v);  // Error 2
    for (int const e : jv) std::cout << e << ' ';
    std::cout << '\n';
}
```

I get errors:

```
1. No member named 'views' in namespace 'std'
2. No member named 'join_view' in namespace 'std::ranges'
```

That reference site says these things are available "since C++20". I have my language build setting at the maximum: `C++2b`. The `clang --version` reports: Apple clang version 14.0.0 (clang-1400.0.29.102).

Is there a way to make this work with Xcode's C++ compiler?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

AppleClang does not support C++ views. See the red boxes in the 4th column on [C++ compiler support](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/compiler_support).

Comment: I don't see mention of views under "C++20 library features", but yeah, a lot of red for rows about views under C++23. Frustrating.

Comment: If I remember it right, AppleClang is still C++98 compiler by default, whereas other compilers set C++14 or C++17 default language.

Comment: For C++20, it's a single line in that table: The One Ranges Proposal.